# label not updating on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am running a synchronise process on the main thread because I don't want the user to try and do anything else during the process.  However I want to update the interface.

For the most part it does update, but sometimes the label I have has not quite caught up to the text I have set it.

Is there a way of forcing the UI to refresh.

I'm very scared I'm going to get clubbed about using a second thread....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set text values on a background thread, have it call out to a method running on the main thread to update UI.  None of the UI elements are thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run the Runloop once in a while while processing:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate distantPast]];
```